# awk getting rid of blank spaces

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am creating a script that checks to see if the first character in the second line of an output file is   " " (blank or not). If it is blank I want to echo 'yes' if not echo 'no'. I am trying this at the moment.
the test file contains the following:

```
###############
              #
# #############
#             #
# ######### # #
#         # # #
# ### ##### # #
#   #     # # #
# # ###########
# #            
###############
```

and my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

line2=$(awk 'NR==2 {print; exit}' < test)
blank_check="${line2:0:1}"
if [ "blank_check" == " " ];
then
    echo "yes"
else    
    echo "no"
fi
```

the problem seems ot be in the line `line2=$(awk 'NR==2 {print; exit}' < test)` as this gets rid of all the blanks spaces and the line2 end up equal to "#" instead of " "

are there any other better ways I can test if the first character of the second line is " "?

Comment: Should the variable in the `if` have a `$` ?  `if [ "$blank_check" == " " ];`

Answer (score 3):

A simple

```
awk 'NR==2 && /^ / {print "yes"}' test
```

should work.

Or:

```
awk -vbool=no 'NR==2 && /^ / {bool="yes";exit} END {print bool}' test
```

Or:

```
awk 'NR==2{print ($0~/^ /)?"yes":"no"; exit}' test
```

If you insist in having both a yes and a no.

---

Speed of the test seems to be ok (tests were repeated several times and also were swapped, not shown to be brief):

```
$ printf '%s\n' $(1 5000000) >testa
$ printf '%s\n' "     #" >>testa

$ time awk '{print substr($0,1,1)==" "?"yes":"no"}NR==2000000{exit}' testa >/dev/null
run    : 0m2.437s sec

$ time awk '{print ($0~/^ /)?"yes":"no"}NR==2000000{exit}' test3 >/dev/null
run    : 0m1.746s sec
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==2{ print substr($0, 1, 1)==" "?"yes":"no"; exit }' infile
```

the [`substr(s, i [, n])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-portability-16) function return the at most `n`-character substring of `s` starting at `i`; so we checks first character of a line if that was space " " print "yes" else "no" (we checks with Ternary operator, condition?"if-true":"if-false").

---

Answer to the similar question (checking second last line from end of the file and also for last character of a line):

```
awk -v rvrslineNr=1 '
BEGIN{ cmd="/usr/bin/wc -l <\"" ARGV[1] "\""; cmd |getline NrLines; close(cmd) }
NR==NrLines-rvrslineNr { print substr($0, length(), 1)==" "?"yes":"no" }' infile
```

set *`rvrslineNr=`* with a number indicates the line number from the end of input file. setting to 0 indicate for very last line, 1 for second last line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
sed '2!d; s/^[^ ].*/no/; s/^$/no/; s/^ .*/yes/' file
```

This deletes all lines apart from the second line.  On the second line, it replaces the line with the string `no` if it starts with a non-space or if it's empty, and with `yes` if it starts with a space.  This `yes` or `no` will be outputted.