# Bash checking to see if a line only has a certain characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

i am wanting to check that the first line of a file to see if it contains only "X", if it contains somthing other then "X" on the first line then i want to echo "yes" if not echo "no"
for example:

the first line in a file is `XXXXXXX` i need the output to be yes

additionally how can i do this with the last line as well ?

Comment: I think `if it contains something other than "X" on the first line then I want to echo "yes"; if not echo "no"` and `the first line in a file is XXXXXXX I need the output to be yes` conflict with each other. Additionally: I wouldn't say an empty line "contains only X" and I wouldn't say and empty line "contains something other than X". What should the output be in case of an empty line?

Comment: You have three other questions on the same topic. You have not accepted any answers on those questions and you have not proven that you have learnt anything from the answers. [Question 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644463/bash-looping-through-characters-not-working), [Question 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644528/awk-getting-rid-of-blank-spaces), [Question 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645168/unable-to-grab-the-last-character-of-from-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

The following script takes a filename as a parameter and checks if the first and the last line are composed of only X characters

```
#!/bin/bash

echo First line
if [ "$(head -n 1 $1 | grep '^X\+$')" == "" ]; then
    #echo something else than X found in the first line
    echo no
else
    #echo only X found in the first line
    echo yes
fi

echo Last line
if [ "$(tail -n 1 $1 | grep '^X\+$')" == "" ]; then
    #echo something else than X found in the last line
    echo no
else
    #echo only X found in the last line
    echo yes
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the title ("… if a line only has a certain characters") I assume "only `X`" means "only `X` character**s**", not strictly "only one `X` character".

With `sed`. Let me start with checking the last line because it's more general:

```
sed -n -e '$ ! d' -e '/^X*$/ ino' -e '/^X*$/ ! iyes' -e '$ q'
```

To check the N-th line replace `$` in the first and in the last expression with N. E.g. for N=5:

```
sed -n -e '5 ! d' -e '/^X*$/ ino' -e '/^X*$/ ! iyes' -e '5 q'
```

N=1 can be simplified because in this case we don't need the first expression and the last one can be just `q`:

```
sed -n -e '/^X*$/ ino' -e '/^X*$/ ! iyes' -e q
```

Notes:

- If there is no N-th line then there will be no output.
- Thanks to `q` `sed` exits as soon as possible (lines after N-th are not processed).
- You can use `^XX*$` instead of `^X*$`. These will generate different output if the line in question happens to be empty. To test for a line being exactly `X` use `^X$`.
- In the general case N appears twice and `^X*$` appears twice. It's not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) but you can use shell variables:

  ```
  N='$'
  pattern='^X*$'
  sed -n -e "$N ! d" -e "/$pattern/ ino" -e "/$pattern/ ! iyes" -e "$N q"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar way as in my previous answers to your questions ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644536/116858) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644590/116858)): Delete all other lines and replace the current line with the string `yes` or `no` depending on whether it contains any other character than *a single* `X`.

```bsh
sed '1!d; s/^X$/no/; t; s/.*/yes/' file
```

The pattern `^X$` matches a lone `X` on a line, so the first substitution would replace the whole line with the string `no` if there is only a single `X` character on it.  The `t` command by itself skips the rest of the script if the most recent `s///` command made a change.

To look at the last line, use `$` in place of `1` in the `sed` code:

```bsh
sed '$!d; s/^X$/no/; t; s/.*/yes/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `AWK` checking the first line:

```
awk '{ print $0!="X"?"yes":"no"; exit }' infile
```

same for checking the last line:

```
awk 'END{ print $0!="X"?"yes":"no" }' infile
```

and checking on N<sup>th</sup> line (replace `N` in *`NR==N`* with the line-number you want verify it is only `X` or not; `NR==line#`):

```
awk 'NR==N{ print $0!="X"?"yes":"no"; exit }' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also consider lines that may contain NUL characters (or more generally non-text, which also includes sequence of bytes not forming valid characters or lines longer than `LINE_MAX` or lines not delimited by a newline character), you may need to switch to `zsh` as other shells can't cope with that easily, and text utilities are not guaranteed to either:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
if IFS= read -r line < file; then
  case $line in
    ("")     print -u2 empty;
    (*[^X]*) print -u2 does not contain only Xes;;
    (*)      print OK, only Xes;;
  esac
else
  print -u2 a full lines could not be read
fi
```

Or resort to `perl`:

```
perl -e '
  open FILE, "<", "file" or die "Cannot open: $!\n";;
  $_ = <FILE>;
  die "a line could not be read\n" unless defined $_;
  die "a full line could not be read\n" unless /\n$/;
  chomp;
  die "does not contain only Xes\n" if /[^X]/;
  print "OK, only Xes\n"'
```